# "Calling server from ten machines" VS "Calling server from one machine with ten copies of client"

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, load-testing

I want to test the load-handling and efficiency in terms of time and resource. I have written a client for that purpose.
Can anyone tell me what is the difference between "Calling server from ten machines" and "Calling server from one machine with ten copies of client"? **Which scheme is better to use and why?**

Comment: Not a problem. I've had 4 VM Sphere servers each with 50 VMs each of which was running 80 test clients to test a 'Server' under various performance and stress scenarios. Unless you're client is sucking up resources I can't see an issue. However, if you can afford to run one client per machine go for it.

Comment: Like @StevieB says, loads of clients running on the same box as server is not a problem from a functionality POV.  Obviously, the impact of the machine resources from the clients depends on what exactly the clients are doing, ie. how much do they use up.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate thing is the resources on your one machine running 10 clients. You've got the network usage of 10 clients over a single network device.

Depending on what the client is doing, you've also got the CPU and mem usaage to factor in. If you have 10 machines, I'd use them

Answer (score 2):

These two are essentially the same in your case. However, having too many threads/processes on one machine may slow down the load generator and the test measurement may not be accurate.

Image thousands of threads (emulating thousands of virtual clients) all compete for CPU and memory resources - the load generator itself may become a bottleneck.

When it comes to per machine capacity, using thread will not scale. That's why performance test tools such as [gatling](http://gatling-tool.org/), [NetGend](http://www.netgend.com) don't use thread in emulating clients. They have much higher scalability.